# What does my program crash sometimes C++?

Tags: c++

So I was to create a program that would verify a password is created correctly.  To pass verification, the user must enter 6 or more characters, have at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, and one digit.  The catch is I had to use only the cstring (and of course cctype) library and not the string library. The program runs fine if the user creates an incorrect password, if they successfully create a good password then it sometimes (not sure why sometimes) it crashes.  An answer to this, will help me solidify my understanding more on pointers an allocation of memory in terms of it being dynamic.  With that here is the program in question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

bool isVerifyAccepted(char*, int);

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 6;
    char *userPass = new char[SIZE];

    cout << "Verify you have a good password\na good password has to be at least six characters long\n" 
     << "have at least on uppercase and one lowercase letter and at least one digit" <<endl <<endl;

    cout << "enter a password below" <<endl <<endl;
    cin >> userPass;

    int userSizePass = strlen(userPass);  
    char testPassWord[userSizePass];      

    int count = 0;
    while (count < userPass[count]) {
        testPassWord[count] = userPass[count];
        count++;
    }

    isVerifyAccepted(testPassWord, userSizePass);


    delete[] userPass;
    userPass = NULL;

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool isVerifyAccepted(char *pass, int size){
    bool verify[3];
    if(size <= 6){
       cout << "Password is too short "<<endl;
       return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(islower(pass[i])){
           verify[0] = true;
           break;
        }else{
           verify[0] = false;      
        }  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(isupper(pass[i])){
           verify[1] = true;
           break;
        }else{
           verify[1] = false;      
        }  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(isdigit(pass[i])){
            verify[2] = true;
            break;
        }else{
            verify[2] = false;      
        }  
    }

    if(verify[0] == false){
        cout << "You need at least one lowercase letter" << endl;          
    }

    if(verify[1] == false){
        cout << "You need at least one uppercase letter" << endl;          
    }

    if(verify[2] == false){
       cout << "You need at least one digit" << endl;          
    }

    if((verify[0] == true) && (verify[1] == true) && (verify[2] == true)){
       cout << "You have a good password, you met the criteria " <<endl;
    }

    return verify;     
}
```

Comment: ***To pass verification, the user must enter 6 or more characters*** and yet you have allocated space for 5 characters + null terminator.

Comment: It crashes where exactly?  The debugger should point to a specific instruction (line).

Comment: When you run it in the debugger does it crash (even sometimes)? If you don't know because you haven't tried... that should be a step you take before posting. Beyond that... see the first comment, which tells you why you're experiencing undefined behavior (which sometimes means crashing - but it's undefined, so not necessarily crashing).

Comment: don't do char *userPass = new char[SIZE]; unless you really need to new something, here char userPass[SIZE+1] would have worked perfectly. Where I am taking the null termination into account.

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant noise about the disclosure, I notice alot of times commentators ask for what purpose this is for, so I figured I would post the disclaimer, and thanks folks for pointing my error, now I know what to do when I encounter this in the future

Comment: Thanks for the comment Phillip, I thought I had to use new char because I don't know the length of the password the user would enter and so I thought to make it dynamic to expand to whatever length.  Perhaps I am in error in thinking that is what it is for

Comment: Using std::string instead of a c array would be the correct c++ way to do this although I expect your class has not taught you that yet. With std::string you do not have to worry about how many characters the user types so there is no chance of UB.

Comment: Oh, yes the string library would of worked better, the instructor's perhaps wanted us to know the cstring in case we encounter this in the field and not rely on string at least that is my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line according to the debugger : `const int  SIZE = 6`.

Increase the size  to `32` or some number larger than `6`.
Some  passwords are longer than 6 characters.

Comment: Though I thought about increasing the size, I felt that was arbitrary, so I kept the minimum and thought to use new char to dynamically allocate new space in case if user enters more characters, was I wrong to use new char that way?

Comment: @dragonore: Increasing the size is arbitrary, it just moves the threshold for a crash a little further away. If you can't use `std::string` the instructor may want you to implement your own dynamic string class (or a minimal working version).

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm sorry if I keep pestering about this to everyone, but was it okay to use new char that way in order to dynamically allocate space for a password to which I do not know the length?  Your input will help we solidify my understanding of dynamic allocation and at a larger context know more about pointers, thanks.

Comment: @dragonore: No you are not wrong using 'new' like that, the Semantics are correct. You just have to anticipate in advance that some users will enter larger than what you would think is the normal size of data.

Comment: @dragonore: If you want to use `new[]` to dynamically allocate more space as needed, then you have to actually do it. At this time I see nothing like that in your code. You allocated a buffer of size 6 and you never make any efforts to reallocate it to make it larger. The buffer will not grow by itself.

Comment: Under these restrictions I would just make an array of 1024 characters and skip the dynamic allocation completely.